# Unable to display view page using ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am getting the following error while trying to display data in view page using ASP.NET MVC2.

> Error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Person' does not exist in the namespace 'Test3.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 170:    
Line 171:    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGlobalScopeAttribute()]
Line 172:    public class views_home_index_aspx : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Test3.Models.Person>, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler {
Line 173:        
Line 174:        private static bool @__initialized;

Source File: c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\86f20dd8\a41e18c\App_Web_index.aspx.a8d08dba.z89z2bzv.0.cs    Line: 172
```

My code files are given below.

> index.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Test3.Models.Person>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
    <p><% Html.TextBoxFor(Model=> Model.Name); %>Html</p>
    <p>
        To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

> Person.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Test3.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; };
    }
}
```

> HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Test3.Models;
namespace Test3.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Name = "subhrajyoti";

            return View(p);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

When i am running using `ctrl+f5` i got the above error.Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Is Test3 a separate project from the project that you executed? If this is the case, check your project assembly linkage and verify that the target framework of all projects involved are the same to resolve this problem. Hope it helps.